# Regex to split alphanumeric string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

How do i use regex to split the string if it's "Amazon2204231550PE" as ['Amazon','2204231550PE'] and "Amazon-P2204231550PE" to ['Amazon-P','2204231550PE'] in python.

Comment: Capture the alpha into one group and the numer into another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` as follows:

```py
inp = "Amazon2204231550PE"
parts = re.findall(r'^[A-Z]+|[0-9]+.*$', inp, flags=re.I)
print(parts)  # ['Amazon', '2204231550PE']
```

Comment: Also could you help me to split if "Amazon-N2204281500PE" to ['Amazon-N','2204281500PE'] also if "Amazon2204231550PE" to ['Amazon','2204231550PE']

Comment: I won't give any updates here.  You should not change your question after it has been answered.  Instead, next time you ask here please include _all_ variations of the inputs.